# Taking multiple lists as arguments rather than returning them in a dict, is there a better way (python3)?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a function where I need to return 2 lists that are created inside the function in python 3.x. Rather than returning the lists I can rather take the 2 lists as arguments and append whatever info I need in those lists. My other approach would be to return a dictionary with the 2 lists and then get the lists my using the key after the function returns. Both these methods require preparation before/after the function call, so I'm just wondering if there is a better way of returning the lists, and if not which of these 2 approaches are better.

Example code:

```
def method1(list1, list2):
    *do something to lists*

def method2():
    *do something to lists*
    return({'list1': list1, 'list2': list2})

get_lists_method1():
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    method1()

get_lists_method2():
    list_dict = method1()
    list1 = list_dict['list1']
    list2 = list_dict['list2']
```

Edit, method using tuples:

```
def method3():
    *create and do something with lists*
    return (list1, list2)

get_lists_method3():
    list1, list2 = method3()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use tuple assignment. Since the two return values go together, just return (list1, list2)

```
# returns a tuple of two lists
def method1(list1, list2):
    list1.append(4)
    list2.append(8)
    return (list1, list2)

# the lists are result[0] and result[1]
result = method1([1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6])
for l in result:
    print l

# more useful: tuple assignment
(list1, list2) = method1([1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6])
print list1
print list2
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't consider tuples using unpacking. from my example it would be `list1, list2 = method2()` if it returned a tuple instead of a dict. Also if your making changes to a list your passing as a argument, isn't it kinda redundant to returns it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a **[tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)**:

```
def method1(lst1=[], lst2=[]):
    # do stuff to lst1 and lst2
    lst1.append("Hello, ")
    lst2.append("world!")
    return (lst1, lst2)

def method2(lst1=[], lst2=[]):
    # do stuff to lst1 and lst2
    lst1.append("lst1")
    lst2.append("lst2")
    return (lst1, lst2)

def main():
    m1_result = method1() # no arguments provided, so defaults are used
    m2_result = method2(["List 1"], ["List 2"])

    print(m1_result)
    print(m2_result)

    print(m1_result[0])
    print(m1_result[1])
    print(m2_result[0])
    print(m2_result[1])

main()
```

Also, assuming you are the one writing methods 1 and 2, you can specify a default value for your parameters if they are not provided when the function is called.